# No scroll momentum/inertia

Tags: android, scroll, phonegap-build, momentum, html-framework-7

I'm developing a mobile web app using framework7 and phonegap build and i'm testing on android device. I'm using framework7's inline pages layout and i can't manage to get scroll inertia or momentum (the feature that make a long page scrolling even after the user release the touch ending the gesture, not sure what's it's name).
Atm i have no clue what to look at to obtain this behaviour. I know framework7 uses native scrolling but the device can definetly scroll on other pages and apps as i would like to.

I also tried to replicate the http://www.idangero.us/framework7/examples/tab-bar/ example copying the source files in my app but still couldn't reach the desired scroll momentum.

Any hint or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: its got fixed https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/commit/0259711e4ae7c621b23602ff65c083b7f3cade52

Comment: noticed! the issue was related to the fastclicks implementation of framework7. before the new release i managed to get scroll inertia adding an option to my framework7 app builder: fastClicks: false. Credits to Vladimir Kharlampidi http://www.idangero.us/framework7/forum/#!/getting-started:no-scroll-inertiamomentum